# Need help with jquery sorting

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have a column within which are multiple 'records' (each a div). 
Each record has a bunch of fields (each a span whose id is the fieldname).

I want to allow the user to sort all the records based on a field. I also want, the field that has been sorted to be moved to the beginning of the record. So I came up with this. But its really slow for a large sets. Not sure whats the best way to do this. Any ideas?

```
$(".col1 div").sort(
  function (a,b)
  {
     if($(a).children("."+field).text() > $(b).children("."+field).text())
          return -1;
     else
           return 1;
  }).appendTo(".col1");
```

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to extract your data into javascript objects and then reorder/render the table with the new sort order. You could make one pass (or serialize your data into a json object directly on the page when you render it out server side) that pulls your data into objects.

```
data = []
$.each("div",function(i,node){
    var x = $(node);
    data.push({name:x.find(".name"),field:x.find(".field")});
})

// sort the data
sorted = data.sort(function(a,b){ return a['field'] > b['field'] });
// then either rewrite the dom or reorder the dom using the id of each div.
```

Dom lookups are really expensive, sorting in code will be much faster.

Comment: Makes sense. Need to try this out. Thanks!